# Would it always necessary to recompile if I modify the implementation details?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, header-files

For example, I have the following `A.h` header file:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A {
public:
    void doSomething();
};

#endif
```

And the following `A.cpp` file as its implementation:

```
#include "A.h"

void A::doSomething() {
    // Implementation
}
```

Then I have a `B.cpp` file which just includes the `A.h` header file, but does not use the `A` class.

Now, if I made some changes to the `A` class, for example, maybe the return type of the doSomething function, do I need to recompile the `B.cpp` file?

If `B.cpp` file create an `A` class object and uses the member function, would the situation be any different?

An answer I got from GPT:

> If you modify the implementation (cpp file) of class A, then any cpp files that include class A's header will need to be recompiled. This is because changes in the implementation can affect how class A's functions are called and how its members are used.

But I think it does not make sense, I suppose only when I modified the `A` interface and I also use `A`'s interface, then I have to recompile the `B` file, is that right?

Comment: Why does B.cpp include the A header at all, since it does not use the A class?  Follow this rule:  **include what you use**.  Don't include what you don't use.

Comment: ChatGPT is wrong. This is the principle of separate compilation. B only needs the interface of A (i.e. only the .hpp is included, not the .cpp). Consequently, if the interface doesn't change, B does not need to be recompiled. This is the issue with AIs, they do not reason, they cannot check what they say. All they say is only the mathematical weighted result of it's algorithm, given a specific dataset on which it was/is trained and an input we provide.

Comment: Technically, *any* change in the source code will require someone somewhere to recompile something. The question is how much it would need to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your understanding, and the previous information provided to you was incorrect.

1. **If you modify only the implementation (i.e., A.cpp) but do not change the interface (i.e., A.h):**
   You do not need to recompile B.cpp if it includes A's header file but does not use the A class. However, you will need to recompile A.cpp and relink the affected object files to ensure that the final executable uses the updated implementation.
2. **If you change the interface (e.g., modifying the return type of `doSomething` in A.h):**
   If B.cpp includes A.h and uses the A class, then you would need to recompile B.cpp and relink the affected object files. If B.cpp includes A.h but does not use the A class, you would still need to relink but wouldn't need to recompile B.cpp.

In summary, changing the implementation (without altering the interface) necessitates recompiling the modified implementation file and relinking the affected object files. Changing the interface may require recompiling other files that use the modified class, and relinking will always be necessary to ensure that the final executable is consistent with the latest code changes.

Comment: And to clarify: You DO need to relink.

Comment: Is the part _"... but does not use the A class"_ really necessary? Even if `B` actually uses `A` and the `A` interface is unchanged, `B.cpp` doesn't need to recompile, only relink.

Comment: *"If B.cpp includes A.h and uses the A class"*. Even if you don't use `A` (but then you probably won't need to include A.h).